# Using analytics raw data in BigQuery

Tags: analytics, raw-data

Ii it possible to load own (my traced website with GA) analytics raw data using a GAP account, and now make deeper analysis with BigQuery?

Comment: Yes, it is totally possible! Please view this article as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920753/raw-bigquery-log-data-for-1st-day-installers/45922099#45922099

Answer (score 0):

If you contact you GAP re-seller then he/she should enable the BigQuery integration for your account and you will not need do anything. Otherwise if you have raw analytics data you can upload it into BigQuery yourself (but you will need tohandle tha update process if this is not a once off thing)